# How to Select Month from Combobox with php?

Tags: php, html, combobox

I have a combobox and It consists of the Month. the following code :

```
<select name='Bmonth' id='Bmonth'>
  <option value='1'>January</option>
  <option value='2'>February </option>
  <option value='3'>March</option>
  <option value='4'>April</option>
  <option value='5'>May</option>
  <option value='6'>June</option>
  <option value='7'>July</option>
  <option value='8'>August</option>
  <option value='9'>September</option>
  <option value='10'>October</option>
  <option value='11'>November</option>
  <option value='12'>December</option>
</select>
```

I want the page number is 4 received, Combobox to view 'April'. for example , if the address of page http//test.php?page=4,combobox view April ... No change in the combobox code!

Comment: this is almost exactly the same as your last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087986/how-to-select-numbers-from-combobox-with-php/23088126#23088126

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a GET Parameter, so do:

```
<?php
//checking if GET URL exists, if yes store it in variable
$page = (isset($_GET['page']))?$_GET['page']:''; 
?>
<!-- checking if variable value is 4, if yes, select the option -->
<option value='4' <?php echo ($page==4)?'selected':''?> >April</option>
```

and so on for all the options.

You could do this through javascript too, but since you haven't place javascript tag in your question, I'm not explaining that.

Answer (score 0):

Define an array of months. Receive the month number via `$_GET` and store it in a variable. Get the corresponding month name from the array. Loop through the month array, and on each iteration, check if the month selected by the user is same as the current month (`$name`). If so, set `$selected` equal to `selected='selected'`. If not, set it to an empty string. Print the `<option>` tag.

```
<select name='Bmonth' id='Bmonth'>
    <?php
        $months = array(
            1=>'January','February','March','April',
            'May','June','July ','August','September',
            'October','November','December',
        );

        $key = $_GET['page'];     // Month number
        $default = $months[$key]; // Month name

        foreach ($months as $num => $name) {
            $selected = ($name == $default) ? "selected='selected'" : "";
            printf('<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>', $num, $selected, $name);
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Selecting a particular option in `SELECT TAG` works like this -

```
<SELECT>
<OPTION>Something
<OPTION SELECTED>Something Else       // This option gets selected
```

In your case, you can assign the `attr selected` using `prop()` of jquery

```
<?php
   $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : "";
?>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").val("<?php echo $pg ?>").prop('selected', 'true');
});
```